sticky position does not work, this is my css and html code
CSS Code
I do not have any parent or grandparent element with overflow: hidden.
<div class="header">
            <section class="top">
                <div class="links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ri-information-2-fill"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ri-mail-fill"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ri-twitter-fill"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ri-facebook-fill"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ri-youtube-fill"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="profile">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>Personal area</span>
                        <i class="ri-user-3-fill"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
            <header>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="logo-container">
                        <img src="logo/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <nav class="nav-bar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About us <i class="ri-arrow-down-s-line"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services <i class="ri-arrow-down-s-line"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog <i class="ri-arrow-down-s-line"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>

I have already tried the methods mentioned in other questions but they don't work for me.
aaaa.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

just some feedback - a screenshot of code is annoying for people trying to answer your question to work with :)

Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow. Please copy and paste your CSS into your post, as you have done with your HTML. Then read this excellent article on how sticky positioning really works.

Why did you put your HTML code as text but not the CSS code?

First thing is that your CSS is targetting the <header> element NOT the element with a class of 'header'. I am not sure if that is intended or not.
If it WAS intended and you just want the <header> element to be sticky, then the problem is that sticky elements only stick until their parent element scrolls off the screen. In your case the parent element doesn't have any content below the <header> element so it scrolls off as soon as the <header> element reaches the top. Add some content below the <header> element and you will see it stick until the content you added scrolls off. Probably the easiest thing to do is to move the <header> element up one level so it is not wrapped in the div with class 'header'
